# Python script for finding a word in a text and returning text and count

Tags: python, text-files

I have a text file containing a small text. I need a script in python that will allow me to look for a specific word (e.g. "food") and which will print the immediate preceding 5 characters and which will also print the total number of occurrences of the word ("food") at the end.

Example:

**"You won't need to bring a lot of food with you. Before packing your food you should run through the wish list. All food will be inspected upon arrival."**

Desired result:

**"t of", "your ", " All "**

**3**

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm a newbie so I've tried a couple of functions without success, namely using infile.seek (keyword) with "food" as keyword and with if word in mystring etc.
Failed both times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if it helps.

```
>>> s = "You won't need to bring a lot of food with you. Before packing your food you should run through the wish list. All food will be inspected upon arrival."
>>> t = "food"
>>> s.split(t)
["You won't need to bring a lot of ", ' with you. Before packing your ', ' you should run through the wish list. All ', ' will be inspected upon arrival.']
>>> result = [part[-5:] for part in s.split(t)[:-1]]
>>> print result
['t of ', 'your ', ' All ']
>>> print len(result)
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to capture the five preceding characters.

`(.{5})` means capture any (`.`) five (`{5}`) characters which are followed by the string `"%s" % word` which embeds the string associated with the variable `word` into the text like so: `"%s" % "food"` -> `"food"`.

```
>>> import re
>>> word = 'food'
>>> m = re.findall(r'(.{5})%s'%word,t)
>>> print m,len(m)
['t of ', 'your ', ' All '] 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation alongside your suggestion. It really helped me think of more than one solution. M appreciated.